# Back-To-Top button glitching with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I am making a back-to-top button for my website and I have the following settings;
My HTML code:

```
<div class="back-to-top">A</div>
```

My CSS:

```css
.back-to-top{position: fixed; right: 60px; font-family: iconFont; font-size: 20px; color:#666; padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px; background-color: rgba(00, 00,00,0.3); border-radius: 5px; dislpay: none;}
.back-to-top:hover{cursor: pointer; color: #2E2E2E; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);}
```

My JavaScript:

```
$('.back-to-top').click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 400);
   return false;
 }); 

$(window).scroll(function () {
                var height = $('body').height();
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                  if(scrollTop > 100){
                      $('.back-to-top').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'bottom' : '50px' , 'display' : 'block'});
                }
                  else {
                     $('.back-to-top').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'bottom': '-50px' , 'display' : 'none'});
                }
            });
```

My problem is that when ever I load the page the button appears at the top right of the page, where it shouldn't be, but when I scroll it disappears and then functions normally. Also when I reload the page at any point in the middle, there isn't any glitch whatsoever. How do I fix my button from appearing at the top of my corner when reloading the page at the very top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/tQuK5/2/ it works by adding

```
display: none;
```

to your css. You had declared this as dislpay: none; which made things a little misleading.

Comment: Thanks! Silly me didn't notice!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look as though you have a vertical position set for the button. You are only adding this via your JavaScript when the page is scrolled.

Try adding `bottom:50px` to you css to set the initial position of the button

Comment: This isn't my problem, my problem is that my button appears from the very **top** of the page where it shouldn't. It should appear when the scroll is higher that 100.